# Unable to add new column to a table using migration in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, migration

I am using laravel to add a column place into the user table. I created a new migration with a name 2017_05_18_025207_add_username_field_to_users_table .. and modified it describing the schema and all in up() and down(). However when i tried to migrate it using PHP artisan migrate . Its not reflected in the database.

```
class AddUsernameFieldToUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    { 
        Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table)
            {
                $table->string('place');
            }); 
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *  
     * @return void
    */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table)
            {
                $table->dropColumn('place');
            });
    }
}
```

this code is what i wrote in the new migration
.

Comment: Did you see any errors when you tried to migrate?  Also did this appear in your migrations table after you ran it?

Comment: no it didnt appear in my migration table. And no error is found. Infact in the cmd i got this message  Migrating: 2017_05_18_025207_add_username_field_to_users_table
Migrated:  2017_05_18_025207_add_username_field_to_users_table

Comment: Could it be possibly some caching issue with whatever client you are using to connect to your database?  Try the sql command `describe users;` to make sure the column hasn't actually been added.

Comment: @user3158900 thank u for ur assistance .. its done.. I dont know what was wrong but i rolled back and tried for 2 -3 times finally having the column added.

Answer (score 1):

```
$table->string('place',255);
```

Run composer dump-autoload and run migration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `composer du` command to register migration class and only then run `php artisan migrate` command.

Comment: it didnt help :(